# How to scroll an UITableView when some part of it is under another transparent UIView

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, uiview, scroll

I have some kind of scrolling problem after XCode7.2 update (It was somehow working well before this update)

There is a full page UITableView in a view controller. I create a UIView from a xib file. Then put that new UIView on top of that table. Some part of the view is transparent and I can see the UITableView under that view.

There are some interactive parts on that view, so I cannot disable user interaction.

Before XCode7.2, I was able to scroll the table by tapping the transparent areas of the top UIView and moving my finger upward or downward

But after the update, when I tap the transparent areas, UITableView does not scroll.

Is there a way to make that view ignore if I tap the transparent areas?

I tried

```
override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {

}

override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

}
```

also

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.table.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}
```

but somehow I couldn't be able to move the UITableView when I start a swipe gesture from those transparent parts of the UIView

Comment: What implementation dos you put in those methods you tried?

Comment: can you use images? so we have a better chance of helping..
try enabling or disabling "adjust view insets" option from the view controller options.